# UITableViewCell won't not receiving touches

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autocomplete, autolayout

I am implementing a view that displays a lot of information. The view is scrollable and inside of the view I implemented a non-scrollable table view holding user comments. I have all the auto-layout constraints and it appears to layout correctly however touches are not received below a certain row. It appears that the table view or something is blocking the views below from receiving the events but I am unable to trace down the issue.

I want the main scroll view's content size to grow as the comment table view grows. Keeping the post comment view at the bottom of the table view. Right now I can't select the last cell or the text field.

Comment Cell View
[image: Comment Cell View]

Simulator screenshot
[image: Simulator screenshot]

Here is the code from the table view implementation:

```
    commentsTableView.delegate = self
    commentsTableView.dataSource = self
    commentsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 82
    commentsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    commentsTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    commentsTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 54
    commentsTableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
    commentsTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    commentsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Comments"
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section != 0 { return nil }

    let sectionTitle: String = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)!
    if sectionTitle == "" {
        return nil
    }

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 54))
    let title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(60, 22, tableView.frame.width, 17))
    view.addSubview(title)

    title.text = sectionTitle
    title.textColor = UIColor(red: (74 / 255), green: (74 / 255), blue: (74 / 255), alpha: 1.0)
    title.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    title.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 16.0)

    view.layer.addBorder(.Bottom, color: UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.75), thickness: 0.5)
    title.setNeedsDisplay()
    view.setNeedsDisplay()

    return view
}
```

Comment: Are  you add didselect function for table view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the userInteractionEnabled to true to fire those events.

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

The Comment TextField is the last row of your comment TableView. So put comment TextField code in footer of the TableView as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let commentTextFieldView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50))

       // Your Comment TextField code

        return commentTextFieldView
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }
```

There is an another way to assign Comment TextField view as tableView footer:

myTableView.tableFooterView = commentTextFieldView